Why did the Pope ask Tremblay to arrange Sister Shanumi's transfer to the Vatican in "Conclave"?
In Conclave (2024), Sister Shanumi, a Nigerian nun handling catering during the papal conclave, publicly confronts Cardinal Adeyemi in the cardinals' refectory, causing a commotion.
It is later revealed that Adeyemi, one of the leading candidates for the papacy, fathered a child with Shanumi when she was 19 and he was 30. This confrontation damages Adeyemi's reputation, leading to a loss of support in the subsequent ballots and effectively ending his chances of becoming Pope.
Later, it is revealed that Cardinal Tremblay (played by John Lithgow), another frontrunner for Pope, arranged for Sister Shanumi's transfer to the Vatican. Tremblay claims he did so on the Pope's orders and was unaware of Shanumi's identity or the reason behind the transfer.
Given this context, why did the Pope ask Tremblay, one of the leading candidates for the papacy, to arrange Shanumi's transfer instead of handling it himself or delegating it to another individual? And what was the Pope’s motive for bringing Shanumi to Rome, considering this action could undermine both Tremblay and Adeyemi’s chances?
This seems particularly puzzling because Tremblay and Adeyemi are strong candidates against Tedesco, a reactionary conservative whose views oppose the Pope's liberal reforms. By seemingly sabotaging Tremblay and Adeyemi, the Pope might inadvertently be paving the way for Tedesco to succeed him—an outcome he would likely want to prevent. I'm curious if the Pope's plan fully accounts for that risk and if there's more to it that I'm missing.
Is there additional information from the book on which the film is based?

The movie sets up early on that the late Pope is a mastermind when Bellini mentions that when the Pope plays chess, he's always 8 moves ahead.
So the Pope ostensibly has realized who is likely to succeed him. He doesn't want Cardinal Adeyemi nor Tremblay to be the next Pope. Adeyemi because of his homophobic views (IIRC) and Tremblay because of his corruption ("simony").
I think we can accept that Tremblay is telling the truth when he said he did it on the Pope's behalf and didn't know why, partially because we have been told the Pope is always thinking many moves ahead. Plus, if Tremblay did know about the relationship between Shanumi and Adeyemi, bringing her to the Vatican without attempting to even obfuscate his involvement in the move would be putting himself at risk for blowback.
By using Tremblay to bring Shanumi to the Vatican, the Pope effectively killed two birds with one stone. Shanumi's presence will lead to the revelation of Adeyemi's past, and then when it is revealed that Tremblay was the one who brought Shanumi in, it will make him look bad as well (on top of the corruption charges against him).
Another related piece of evidence is that Cardinal Lawrence (Fiennes) said he wanted to resign but the Pope refused him. This was presumably because the Pope knew that Lawrence was the best one to be around to execute the traps the Pope had laid.
You could argue that this plan is fairly flimsy and contrived, but I think that a certain suspension of disbelief is necessary for this film.
This answer is based solely on the movie. A quick read of the Wikipedia article about the book suggests that the movie's plot is fairly close to what happens in the book (though I wonder if the bit about the chess board was in the book at all).

Something something keep your enemies closer

That's a great analysis, but it still leaves me wondering why the Pope would risk Tedesco becoming the next Pope (question was edited to mention this). Tremblay and Adeyemi are both strong contenders against Tedesco, who represents the reactionary conservative views the liberal Pope opposes. By undermining Tremblay and Adeyemi, it seems like the Pope might be unintentionally helping Tedesco's chances. I'm curious if the Pope's plan fully accounts for that risk and if there's more to it that we're missing.

Yea that’s a bit trickier. The obvious thing would just be that Tedesco never really had enough support and the people supporting the other undermined candidates wouldn’t switch to him on account of his overly extreme views. But that doesn’t seem very convincing. Though Adeyemi’s supporters probably would not switch to Tedesco because he’s clearly racist. But unless the Pope arranged the suicide bombing he couldn’t have known that Benitez would wind up swaying everyone to his side.

@shim - It kind of does seem as if the former Pope might have intended for Benitez to win, doesn't it? Thus his unusual appointment. But I doubt that he was arranging attacks against the church. I suppose that he might have thought that Benitez would be more appealing to the liberal wing than even Bellini for a variety of reasons, as indeed he was, but Tedesco is the sticking point.

@shim - If one assumes that most of Adeyemi's supporters would be inclined to see a Pope from a non-European country with a lot of experience advocating for people from those countries, the former Pope might have guessed most would go for Benitez. And if most of Tremblay's supporters are much less conservative than Tedesco, but think Bellini is too radical or too ambitious, they would vote for an unknown quantity over Bellini if they saw Tremblay losing supporters.

It does seem like Tedesco had a hard but relatively small core of traditionalists while everyone who was a bit non-traditional in some fashion or another was divided between the other three leading candidates, which gave him a chance of winning.

I would agree that the intended implication is that the Pope did engineer things to make Benitez the next pope. The Pope clearly spent a lot of time pursuing his liberal views and didn't want his work undone, and on top of that he essentially wanted to give a middle finger to those with more conservative views by installing Benitez specifically. He couldn't have been certain things would go according to his plan, but if they didn't then the movie wouldn't have happened.
